# C++ SDL2_image library gives undefined references with CMake

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake, sdl-2

I have a C++ project where I want to use the libraries `SDL2` and `SDL2_image`, I downloaded the newest `-VC` version from the official git repos and put them in my project in a folder called external/.

Then I have created a CMakeLists.txt to build my project, there I specified the path to the libraries and used target_link_libraries to link them.

CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(SDL2_DIR "C:/../external/SDL2-2.28.5/cmake")
set(SDL2_image_DIR "C:/../external/SDL2_image-2.8.1/cmake")

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
find_package(SDL2_image REQUIRED)

target_include_directories(main SYSTEM PUBLIC "C:/../external/SDL2-2.28.5/include")
target_include_directories(main SYSTEM PUBLIC "C:/../external/SDL2_image-2.8.1/include")

target_link_libraries(main ${SDL2_LIBRARIES} ${SDL2_IMAGE_LIBRARIES})
```

Now while this works fine for the standard `SDL2` library i get undefined references when I try to use functions from the `SDL2_image` library.

My system runs windows 11, and I use VSCode as an IDE.
The compiler I use is g++.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It doesn't matter what IDE. What compiler do you use?

Comment: ***I downloaded the newest -VC version*** If SDL2 was built for msvc (sounds like that with vc in the name) and you are using MinGW I would expect to see linker errors even with CMake. Also VSCode recommends that if you use MinGW that you install it using msys2. Once you do that use `pacman` to install SDL2 and you will have the proper compatible binaries for your compiler. The msys2 repository is a fantastic resource with thousands of open source libraries which can easily be installed using `pacman`.

Comment: I use g++ as a compiler which I installed with MinGW-w64 toolchain with msys2.

Comment: If you are using ucrt64 MinGW install this package [https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-SDL2?repo=ucrt64](https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-SDL2?repo=ucrt64) with this install command in your urct64 terminal `pacman -S mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-SDL2` and get CMake to use that instead of the msvc version you downloaded.

Comment: Ok so I installed the pacman package you mentioned aswell as the sdl2_image package (https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-SDL2_image) and told cmake to use them instead of the ones in my external folder. But I still get the same undefined reference errors.

Comment: Can you add the errors? Also maybe the build command?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it using this command in the CMakeLists.txt:

target_link_libraries(main SDL2::SDL2main SDL2::SDL2 SDL2_image::SDL2_image)

instead of:

target_link_libraries(main ${SDL2_LIBRARIES} ${SDL2_IMAGE_LIBRARIES})

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).